# Inserting into field1,field2 from a select field1, field2 populates only 1 field

Tags: php, mysql

I am inserting into a table from `SELECT field1, field2`, but only **field1** is populated not **field2.

```
$query_settings = 
    "INSERT INTO email_sent (field1, field2) 
     SELECT field1, field2 
     FROM field_id 
     WHERE id='$x'";
```

What possibly could I be missing?

Comment: What are the data types of the `field2` columns in both tables?

Comment: @eggyal Can you put this as your answer, its the data type...Thanks..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the data types of the respective `field2` columns: there may be some implicit type conversion taking place that's truncating the data.

Answer (score 1):

You should always check the line after a query was run, for instance:

```
Query OK, 3 rows affected (0.02 sec)
Records: 3  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
```

Pay special attention to the `Warnings` counter; due to failed data type conversions you may end up with `NULL` values, but that would show in the above.

To show the warnings:

```
SHOW WARNINGS;
```